# How can I convert numbers with "subscript" fractions to decimal in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, converters, vba

I have thousands of numbers that were given to me in an unusable format for calculations:

```
9⅝, 9¼, 9¾, 10¼
```

This is how they appear in each row in Excel. I would like to convert these to a decimal. I've tried `=FIXED(A2, 3)` but that did not do the trick. The problem arises because the fractions are in this weird format.

Is there a formula or macro that I can implement to get the desired decimal results?

Thank you very much and happy Easter!

Comment: to confirm - if you had in cell A1 9⅝ and in another cell you use formula `=right(A1, 1)` does it bring back ⅝ or 8?

Comment: @SamGilbert for me, it returns 5/8

Comment: Which source did the numbers come from?

Comment: @SamGilbert I got them off the internet, why?

Comment: The issue, as I see it, is that you can't separate out the nominator and denominator from the fraction, so I was just interested in the source of the numbers to see if there was a better way to bring it in a usable way to excel

Comment: @SamGilbert Ah, no this is the only way I could extract them. So am I looking at a lot of manual work here?

Comment: Please see my potential answer below to see if it's workable for you...

Comment: @SamGilbert what happened to your answer? I preferred that one, I think

Comment: SamGilbert and Gary's Student have both provided essentially the same approach.  One through VBA and one just using excel formulas.  nice work guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each of your fractions is a single unicode character.  If we isolate a single character in a cell and run:

```
Sub WhatsIt()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox Asc(v) & vbCrLf & AscW(v) & vbCrLf & Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(AscW(v))
End Sub
```

we see:

[image]

It now becomes easy to convert these items into real values.  Here is a start:

```
Public Function Konvert(s As Variant) As Double
    Dim d As Double

    d = CDbl(Mid(s, 1, Len(s) - 1))
    If AscW(Right(s, 1)) = 8541 Then d = d + 0.625
    Konvert = d
End Function
```

[image]

You must expand this code to include other fractions.  Here are some common ones:

[image]

Comment: This seems tedious for all of the different fractions, but it is an option. What happened to the other option?

Comment: I will try your solution and @Sam solution, too

Comment: @MJ95  There are only a handful of fractions.

Answer (score 1):

So here is one solution for you. I'm assuming that the format of the number is set and that you can't separate out the fraction.

It requires a bit of manual work and will only really be workable if you have a reasonable amount of fractions that can be manually adjusted

Here goes...

Assuming raw data is in column A, create some helper columns:

- Column B: extract the fraction, for example: `=RIGHT(A2, 1)`
- Column C: use this information to extract now the whole number, for example: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2, B2, "")`

Create a lookup from the unusable fraction format to one that you can use in excel:

- First column in the lookup should be the fraction in unusable format
- Second column should be the fractions in a usable format, first format the cells in second column > Format Cells menu > Number tab > Category as Fraction > Type "Up to one digit (1/4)"
- Manually in the corresponding cells the equivalent values (for example, below in cell H2 write 5/8)

[image]

Now lookup the adjusted fraction in the main table

- Column D: Lookup the adjusted fraction, for example: `=VLOOKUP(B2, $G$2:$H$4, 2, 0)`
- Column E: Recalculate the usable whole number, for example: `=C2 +D2`

Full solution screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: This could work if I finish entering my data and then use this method to "bulk" update all of them at once