# How to convert a "fraction" character into a decimal?

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula

I have a dataset where the format of data is like this:

```
10 ¾ AB 02/15/19
```

I'm trying to convert the `¾` into `.75` so that the data looks like:

```
10.75 AB 02/15/19
```

I am thinking of trying to iterate through each character in the string, but once I do so how can I convert the `¾` into `.75`?

Comment: Can you show some more sample inputs?  Is it always going to be formatted like `## [FRACTION] AB ...`?

Comment: My guess is that the `3/4` is a special symbol and not a number,  you will need to know all the possible symbols and create a cross reference with their proper decimal form.

Comment: Is `¾` a 'vulgar fraction' (single chr(190)) or two unicode chars separated by a slash?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How can I convert numbers with “subscript” fractions to decimal in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245894/how-can-i-convert-numbers-with-subscript-fractions-to-decimal-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks for the link will take a look - how can I check what kind of symbol/character the ¾ is?

Comment: How many backspaces does it take to erase it?

Comment: Just 1 backspace to delete the fraction character

Comment: Then it's chr(190). chr(188) is `¼` and chr(189) is `½`.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find a dictionary of some sort for the char(#) and the symbols they represent?

Comment: @abcdefg12345 http://unicodefractions.com/?

Comment: LOL - "Vulgar" fractions? I had no idea they were named that. Keep in mind that this may also be ties to the code set being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple set of string replacements:

```
Public Function numerify(s As String) As String
    numerify = Replace(s, " " & ChrW(190), ".75")
    numerify = Replace(numerify, " " & ChrW(188), ".25")
    numerify = Replace(numerify, " " & ChrW(189), ".5")
End Function
```

[image]

**NOTES:**

We replace the *space* before the fraction as well as the fraction to get the desired result.
There may be other uni-code "fractions" you may need to consider.

Comment: There are indeed other Unicode fractions: [Unicode Vulgar Fractions](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition/%3Cfraction%3E)  another [Slightly better formatted list](http://unicodefractions.com/) provides both decimal and hex codes.